# Read a number value from a div element and round to 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to retrive a number value from a div and then round that number to 2 decimal places using jQuery.

So far I have the element name and value:

```
<div class="value">Price = £133.3223443</div>
```

I am using the toFixed() method to convert a number into a string then round to 2 decimal places:

```
var inNum = 12345.6789;
inNum.toFixed(2);
```

However, I am having trouble trying to read a number within the element on the page (ignoring 'Price'), rather than just rounding a number entered within the jQuery.

Comment: Why not extract only numbers out of the element's HTML using a regex or may be split the HTML and get everything after £. Wouldnt that suffice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse it with regexp? :)

http://jsfiddle.net/LERFB/2/ <--- working fiddle

```
    var price = $('div.value').text();
    var parsedPrice = parseFloat(price.replace(/([^0-9\.])/g, ''));
    alert(parsedPrice.toFixed(2));
```

Comment: Makes sense... I didn't even know that existed, thanks!

Comment: Wait - i will add regex for the dot :) because it's removing dot as well

Comment: Ok - done -> my answer shows the code that is fully working :)

Comment: Something we all need to remember to save a lot of wtf is that toFixed() returns a string, not a float.

Comment: And that toFixed() has to be invoke on a number, not string  :) - happened to me during creation of this fiddle. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `text()` to get the value from the element, and the `split()` by `£` to get the numerical price. Try this:

```
var inNum = parseFloat($('.value').text().split('£')[1]).toFixed(2);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/n53Ka/)

Obviously you will also need some form of verification to ensure that there is a `£` character in the string to split by, and that the value retrieved is numerical.

Answer (score 0):

The following regular expression will extract the floating numbers from the string and do a toFixed operation.

```
var inNum = parseFloat($(".value").text().match(/[\d\.\d]+/i)).toFixed(2);
```

Please make sure you have the value inside the  container all the time.